# error in nvarchar to date, date not supplied, either problem in onclick event or stored procedure or in gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

For your information, I am using Visual Studio Professional 2010

Can someone please help me out, I think the @dateFound parameter is not supplied with a value on click event.

I have a gridview populated from stored procedure as given below.

```
     <asp:SqlDataSource id="Sql20" 
     ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:connectionString %>'
                      SelectCommand="dbo.StoredProcedure2"
                      Runat="server" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
     </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The storedProcedure2 is as follow which is suppose to show all the data in gridview if @dateFound IS NULL, by default as below

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure2

(
@dateFound DATE 
)
 AS
/* SET NOCOUNT ON */

    IF @dateFound IS NULL

    BEGIN

    SELECT 
        lc_orders_tb.lc_orderID, 
        lc_orders_tb.lc_orderSubTotal, 
        lc_orders_tb.lc_orderTotal,
        lc_orders_tb.LRNo,
        lc_orders_tb.LRDate, 
        lc_orders_tb.lc_orderPlacedDate,
        lc_orders_tb.LInvoiceLoc, 
        lc_orderStatus_tb.lc_orderStatusDescrip,
        lc_orderStatus_tb.lc_delType,
        lc_tb.lc_compName, 
        lc_tb.lc_addCity, 
        (SELECT SUM(lc_orderQuantity)
        FROM lc_orderQuantity_tb 
        WHERE 
    lc_orders_tb.lc_orderID=lc_orderQuantity_tb.lc_OrderID) as lc_orderQuantity
              FROM lc_orders_tb 
                    INNER JOIN
                    lc_tb ON lc_orders_tb.lc_id = lc_tb.lc_id
                    INNER JOIN
      lc_orderStatus_tb ON lc_orders_tb.lc_orderID = lc_orderStatus_tb.lc_orderID
                    ORDER BY lc_orders_tb.lc_orderPlacedDate DESC
    END

    ELSE

    BEGIN
        SELECT 
        lc_orders_tb.lc_orderID, 
        lc_orders_tb.lc_orderSubTotal, 
        lc_orders_tb.lc_orderTotal,
        lc_orders_tb.LRNo,
        lc_orders_tb.LRDate, 
        lc_orders_tb.lc_orderPlacedDate,
        lc_orders_tb.LInvoiceLoc, 
        lc_orderStatus_tb.lc_orderStatusDescrip,
        lc_orderStatus_tb.lc_delType,
        lc_tb.lc_compName, 
        lc_tb.lc_addCity, 
        (SELECT SUM(lc_orderQuantity)
        FROM lc_orderQuantity_tb 
        WHERE 
   lc_orders_tb.lc_orderID = lc_orderQuantity_tb.lc_OrderID) as lc_orderQuantity
              FROM lc_orders_tb 
                    INNER JOIN
                    lc_tb ON lc_orders_tb.lc_id = lc_tb.lc_id
                    INNER JOIN
                    lc_orderStatus_tb ON lc_orders_tb.lc_orderID = lc_orderStatus_tb.lc_orderID
WHERE  
    convert(varchar(10), lc_orders_tb.lc_orderPlacedDate, 103) = @dateFound
                    ORDER BY lc_orders_tb.lc_orderPlacedDate DESC
    END
     RETURN
```

@dateFound will be supplied when clicked on a button click but by default, I mean, when page loads it is not supplied and therefore it should execute the first if statement but it different errors like @dateFound not supplied or error on converting nvarchar to date. The ELSE statement of the SP should get executed if @dateFound supplied from the textbox after clicking on the button. But I cant seem to work out. Please have a look at the click event of the button which is supplying the @dateFound

```
    Protected Sub CustomGV3_onClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        Dim connectionString As String = 
   WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("dbo.StoredProcedure2", con)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue
    ("@dateFound", Format(txtBoxDateFrom.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy"))

        Using con
            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteReader()
            con.Close()
        End Using
        GridView3.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

Can someone please help me out. Does it seem like I have a totally wrong approach ? Can someone please correct me.

awaiting your kind help plz..
Thanking You

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your stored procedure to use a default value for the @dateFound parameter:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure2
(
   @dateFound DATE = NULL
)
AS
```

Comment: @peterSmith Thank you so much, now it works initially when the page loads but when I want want to see the record for a particular date which is by supplying the @dateFound when clicking on a button, error comes up saying that "Error converting data type nvarchar to date." I tried to get rid off it but to no avail. Where might be mistake, in the stored procedure ELSE statement when I am converting to date or in the onclick event when supplying the value to @dateFound ? Or somewhere else ? Thank you for your help, it worked half the way...

Comment: @Saranga, check out this section of your WHERE clause :     convert(varchar(10), lc_orders_tb.lc_orderPlacedDate, 103) = @dateFound. You need to convert to a DATE not a VARCHAR.

Comment: @peterSmith thank you for your reply. I tried simply putting lc_orders_tb.lc_orderPlacedDate but it doesnt work either. How can I convert to a date plz.

Comment: @Saranga, if lc_orderPlacedDate is not a DATE, try something like this: convert(DATE, lc_orders_tb.lc_orderPlacedDate).

Comment: @peter thank you for your reply, I forgot to mention it is a date and still the error is "Error converting data type nvarchar to date." and red colored error line is                              "con.Open()"
             cmd.ExecuteReader()
            con.Close()".... ...The error is shown at cmd.ExecuteReader()

Comment: @Saranga, what is the data type of lc_orderPlacedDate? And can you provide an example of what the data looks like?

Comment: @peterSmith the dataType is date and one of the date from that table such as "02-Jan-01" in the database table and when shown in the gridview it looks like "02-02-2001". It looks like that in the gridview becasue i have formated it like this  Text='<%# eval("lc_orderPlacedDate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")

Comment: @peterSmith Now when I tried datatype of INT of other column to see if the problem is only with the date (column) but then it says that @VARIABLEname was not supplied.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer from other forum, it worked by simply changing following in the SP

```
    (
@dateFound DATE = '01/01/1900'
)
```

The above date is set as default as it will never be going to be in the database against which I will be checking by IF STATEMENT in SP. And in the aspx page to as below.

```
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtBoxDateFrom" 
        Name="dateFound" PropertyName="Text" 
        DbType="Date" DefaultValue="01/01/1900" />
```

Thanks to all contributor who tried to help me out here..